# Serverless application (AWS Lambda function) using OAuth2 authentication

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, serverless, aws-serverless

To anyone that can help me

I've been researching for a long time a way to make a connection between an OAuth2(Facebook in this case) API and my DB but I couldn't find anything the way I need so far. So, I'm asking for help or some light that I can follow...

What I'm trying to do is simples, get my data from the API endpoint and update my table with this data, but authenticating this request has been my big problem.

Problem is:
I need to do this serverless, I mean, I'm planning to create a Node.js AWS Lambda function and trigger it once a day, simple like that.
But I can't find any example that shows me how to do it without a UI interaction to authenticate the new code for the access token.

Is it possible to make it just code-based?
Is there a way?
Am I being ridiculous asking that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The type of token (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) you need in order to access the Facebook graph-api depends on what API you are trying to call on Facebook.

So, which APIs on Facebook do you actually want to call and for what purpose?

Note - once an access token has been created, you can generate a long-lived access token that's good for about 60 days (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/) ... you'll need to update the token in your serverless app every 60 days as well in that case.